# wget not saving links in desired format

Tags: wget

When I use a browser to save this page:
http://maine.craigslist.org/fuo/
the links are saved in such a way that they link to content.
like this:
href="http://maine.craigslist.org/fuo/4323535885.html"

when I try to use wget, the links are

```
$ wget --no-parent maine.craigslist.org/fuo
```

saved as:
href="/fuo/4305913395.html"

I have tried options:

```
--spider
--page-requisites 
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101  Firefox/27.0"
```

but the links all come out without the url attached.

I have the rest of the script working, to parse out my location, and make a new list of links for furniture in my area. But I cannot figure out how to get the same output as I get when I save the page via firefox.

I thought using wget would be simplest. Perhaps that isnt right. If I can achieve the same effect using some other software, so long as i can write a script to make it work, I will be happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--convert-links` option should do what you're looking for:

```
wget --convert-links --no-parent maine.craigslist.org/fuo
```

More information about this option and what it does is below (copied from [`man wget`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/wget)):

```
   --convert-links
       After the download is complete, convert the links in the document
       to make them suitable for local viewing.  This affects not only the
       visible hyperlinks, but any part of the document that links to
       external content, such as embedded images, links to style sheets,
       hyperlinks to non-HTML content, etc.

       Each link will be changed in one of the two ways:

       ·   The links to files that have been downloaded by Wget will be
           changed to refer to the file they point to as a relative link.

           Example: if the downloaded file /foo/doc.html links to
           /bar/img.gif, also downloaded, then the link in doc.html will
           be modified to point to ../bar/img.gif.  This kind of
           transformation works reliably for arbitrary combinations of
           directories.

       ·   The links to files that have not been downloaded by Wget will
           be changed to include host name and absolute path of the
           location they point to.

           Example: if the downloaded file /foo/doc.html links to
           /bar/img.gif (or to ../bar/img.gif), then the link in doc.html
           will be modified to point to http://hostname/bar/img.gif.

       Because of this, local browsing works reliably: if a linked file
       was downloaded, the link will refer to its local name; if it was
       not downloaded, the link will refer to its full Internet address
       rather than presenting a broken link.  The fact that the former
       links are converted to relative links ensures that you can move the
       downloaded hierarchy to another directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you view the page source of the online page in your browser, you'll see that the links are relative in the document. The browser converts them automatically, but wget can't do this.

To have the page display correctly in a browser, the solution would be to use the [HTML <​base> Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_base.asp). Just add `<base href="http://maine.craigslist.org/fuo">` to the head section of the downloaded files and all links will point to the correct absolute location. You can do this automatically in your script.

If you want your script to perform further actions on the links, the best solution would be to have the script add the base url in front of each link.